# Not able to set the headers in the request when navigating through webView.CoreWebView2

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, microsoft-edge, webview2

```
    Namespace: Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms
    Assembly:  Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll
    Package:   Microsoft.Web.WebView2 v1.0.902.49
```

> Assigning to some local folder Path for creating the webView2 environment

```
    string userDataFolder = Path.GetTempPath() + @"NETWebView2UserDataTest";

    CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();

 async void InitwebView()
        {
                CoreWebView2Environment env = CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync("", userDataFolder, options).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
                webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView_CoreWebView2Ready;
        }

 private void WebView_CoreWebView2Ready(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webView.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All);
            webView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;
        }
```

It's Navigating to the Url but headers is not getting set for the request

```
private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set and access the header
            e.Request.Headers.SetHeader("test","username")
             webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(webView.Source.ToString());
       }
```

Comment: When you call `webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate` you're creating a new request, not using the one, you have just changed.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the part of the code you provided, I think you have set the source property for the `WebView2` control, and @Poul Bak has already mentioned the cause of your issue.

In this case, you can try to set attributes and value to the Header in the [NavigationCompleted event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49).

A simple test(test with google):

```
async void InitwebView()
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(default);
            webView.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.com/");
            webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView2Control_CoreWebView2Ready;
        }

private void WebView2Control_CoreWebView2Ready(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webView.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All);
            webView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;
        }

private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Request.Headers.SetHeader("test", "username");
            //webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(webView.CoreWebView2.Source);
        }
```

Result:[image]